# Script to convert multiple SVG images to a SVG font file

Tags: linux, fonts, svg, converters, svg-font

I'm searching for a script to convert multiple SVG images (each containing one letter) to a SVG font file.

Basically the same this website does: http://keyamoon.com/icomoon/app/

But I would prefer a script (preferable Linux), so we can integrate it in our build process.

Any ideas? Or code I can start with?

Input should be a list of SVG images + a mapping file and the output should be one file containing all the SVG images as SVG font.

Comment: http://nodeca.github.com/fontomas/ is another similar webapp.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FYI, two guys just released a project to do this very thing:

https://github.com/FontCustom/fontcustom

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a command line application that creates a SVG font from a set of SVG files and vice versa: https://github.com/madeyourday/SVG-Icon-Font-Generator

It's written in PHP and is currently in beta.

But it's using no mapping file, the mapping is based on the file names.

Answer (score 1):

The [**Apache Batik**](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) project has a [SVG Font](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/font-converter.html) converter which may be an option for you.

From their font converter example:

```
java -jar batik-ttf2svg.jar /usr/home/myFont.ttf -l 48 -h 57 -id MySVGFont -o mySVGFont.svg -testcard
```

Comment: Batiks SVG Font converter converts a TrueType Font to an SVG Font. This could be an option, if I had a script, that would convert my SVG images, to a TrueType Font. Do you know of any?

Comment: I think you would have to write your own. The command line options are documented here -> http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/font-converter.html. I'll update my answer with this link